# How to work out difference between scores at date 1 and future dates for same ID SPSS

Tags: spss, difference

I have a dataset where each ID has visited a website and recorded their risk level which is coded 0-3. They have then returned to the website at a future date and recorded their risk level again. I want to calculate the difference between each ID's risk level from their first recorded risk level.

For example my dataset looks like this:

```
ID Timestamp RiskLevel

1  20-Jan-21    2

1  04-Apr-21    2

2  05-Feb-21    1

2  12-Mar-21    2

2  07-May-21    3

3  09-Feb-21    2

3  14-Mar-21    1

3  18-Jun-21    0
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
ID Timestamp RiskLevel DifFromFirstRiskLevel

1  20-Jan-21     2      .

1  04-Apr-21     2      0

2  05-Feb-21     1      .

2  12-Mar-21     2      1

2  07-May-21     3      2

3  09-Feb-21     2      .

3  14-Mar-21     1     -1

3  18-Jun-21     0     -2
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is with the strategy in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145779/how-to-work-out-time-difference-from-first-timestamp-for-each-id-spss), but I will use a different approach here:

sort cases by ID timestamp.
compute firstRisk=risklevel.
if $casenum>1 and ID=lag(ID) firstRisk=lag(firstRisk).
execute.
compute DifFromFirstRiskLevel=risklevel-firstRisk.